# Suppress warning on unused exception variable in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, exception

I have this code:

```
try {
    someMethod();
} catch (XYZException e) {
    // do something without using e
}
```

Doing this will give me a warning about declaring but never using `e`, which I hate. However, I also don't want to use a `catch` clause without that variable, because then it will catch all exceptions, not just `XYZException`s. This seems like a fairly often occurring pattern. I know I can use `#pragma warning disable 0168` to suppress the warning, but I don't really find that a very elegant solution. Is there a better way?

Comment: "Hate" is such a strong word but, given the set jaw and angry eyebrows of your avatar, possibly apt :-)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Define the catch clause without the exception variable as follows:

```
try {
    someMethod();
} catch (XYZException) {
    // do something without using e
}
```

Comment: I'd love to know why does this work. Is this a catch-only mechanism?

Comment: Why shouldn't it work? `e` (or whatever you put there) casts the exception to an object, which has a cost, so why do it if you don't use it?

Answer (score 34):

Define the catch clause without the exception variable as follows:

```
try {
    someMethod();
} catch (XYZException) {
    // do not state e in catch clause
}
```

Comment: Duplicate entry; wasted time reading this to see what was different. Maybe someone should tidy this up? (Realise it's not _much_ time but seems a waste when they're the same answer :-p)

Comment: Not only did I waste time reading the duplicate entry. I also wasted time reading the comment above flagging this fact. Woe to the curious guy that reads everything.

Comment: Please note that both duplicates are written at the same time.

Comment: @ChristopherLightfoot this answer was actually given 41 seconds before the other one.

Comment: And, on top of that, this one doesn't use any made up words like `exceptionhandler`. Also, it's much more definite, *tellling* you to do something rather than just stating that you *can* do something :-)

Comment: FYI: They are the same now

Comment: If you upvoted Jan's answer, be fair and upvote also Tim's answer as both have answered the question at same point in time - Tim was even first.

Comment: The thing I like about having the variable name is that it's useful when debugging and you can't go back in time and add it when you need it... you would have to restart. Of course there are other ways of getting at the information in that moment so  you don't need to restart but it just takes longer and is disruptive when you get in the zone. Wish Microsoft knew this and just made an exception for... exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use

```
     try 
     {
          someMethod();
     } 
 #pragma warning disable 0168
     catch (XYZException e)
 #pragma warning restore 0168
     {
         // do not state e in catch clause
     }
```

This is useful in visual studio 2015 because it doesn't have a way to see the exception by default when debugging with a breakpoint on the catch.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage` attribute.

[visit Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute?view=netframework-4.8)